# asp is producing unnecessary whitespace within the axes of my R plot. How can I reformat the graph?

Tags: r, plot

I'm trying to create a scatter plot + linear regression line in R 3.0.3. I originally tried to create it with the following simple call to `plot`:

```
plot(hops$average.temperature, hops$percent.alpha.acids)
```

This created this first plot:

[image]

As you can see, the scales of the Y and X axes differ. I tried fixing this using the `asp` parameter, as follows:

```
plot(hops$average.temperature, hops$percent.alpha.acids, asp=1, xaxp=c(13,18,5))
```

This produced this second plot:

[image]

Unfortunately, setting `asp` to 1 appears to have compressed the X axis while using the same amount of space, leaving large areas of unused whitespace on either side of the data. I tried using `xlim` to constrain the size of the X-axis, but `asp` seemed to overrule it as it didn't have any effect on the plot.

```
plot(hops$average.temperature, hops$percent.alpha.acids, xlim=c(13,18), asp=1, xaxp=c(13,18,5))
```

Any suggestions as to how I could get the axes to be on the same scale without creating large amounts of whitespace?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to use `par` parameter `pty` and set it to `"s"`. See `?par`:

> `pty`
>
> A character specifying the type of plot region to be used; `"s"`
>   generates a square plotting region and `"m"` generates the maximal
>   plotting region.

It forces the plot to be square (thus conteracting the side effect of `asp`).

```
hops <- data.frame(a=runif(100,13,18),b=runif(100,2,6))
par(pty="s")
plot(hops$a,hops$b,asp=1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I agree with plannapus that the issue is with your plotting area. You can also fix this within the device size itself by ensuring that you plot to a square region. The example below opens a plotting device with square dimension; then the margins are also set to maintain these proportions:

#### Example:

```
n <- 20
x <- runif(n, 13, 18)
y <- runif(n, 2, 6)
png("plot.png", width=5, height=5, units="in", res=200)
par(mar=c(5,5,1,1))
plot(x, y, asp=1)
dev.off()
```

[image]